# Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched

Tags: java, soap, soapui, weblogic12c

I have several SOAP services deployed on a WebLogic cluster and everytime We invoke one we got this printed on the console.

```
<Jul 19, 2018 5:14:44,520 PM COT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[[HTTP:101402]Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched.] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [HTTP:101402]Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched.
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncContextImpl.getRequest(AsyncContextImpl.java:231)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSAsyncListener$1.onComplete(WSAsyncListener.java:69)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$OnCompleteHandler.handle(AsyncEventsManager.java:223)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$1.run(AsyncEventsManager.java:140)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$1.run(AsyncEventsManager.java:134)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I've google the ERROR and it seems to be related to Async calls on web services but we have non async services deployed nor invoked

This is our Interface

```
<code>
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.FaultAction;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.3-1-04/21/2011 01:08 PM(jitu)-
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "EstadoProvisionI", targetNamespace = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface EstadoProvisionI {


    @WebMethod(action = "http://localhost:7001/Integrator/services/EstadoProvision")
    @WebResult(name = "estadoProvisionResponse", targetNamespace = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/", partName = "parameters")
    @Action(input = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/EstadoProvisionI/estadoProvisionRequest", output = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/EstadoProvisionI/estadoProvisionResponse", fault = {
        @FaultAction(className = EstadoProvisionException_Exception.class, value = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/EstadoProvisionI/estadoProvision/Fault/estadoProvisionException")
    })
    public EstadoProvisionResponse estadoProvision(
        @WebParam(name = "estadoProvisionRequest", targetNamespace = "http://consulta.ws.integrator.company.co/", partName = "parameters")
        EstadoProvisionRequest parameters)
        throws EstadoProvisionException_Exception
    ;

}
</code>
```

Any Light you can throw over this would be appreciated

Comment: Any help on this? anybody?

Comment: Hi Amir did you figure this one out ? I am facing the same issue and I can't find the cause of this.